# Getting app name in Rails AppBuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, generator

I am trying to create a builder for my rails app and for the mysql option I want to create the necessary mysql databases. The thing is I want to name them `appname_development` and `appname_test`. However I couldn't find a way to get the app name in the builder yet.

I tried using `@app_name` to no avail.

Is there another way to get the app name?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
Rails.application.class.parent_name
```

Comment: undefined method `application' for Rails:Module (NoMethodError) is what I got. I wasn't expecting this to work since the app not fully built yet. Is this why it's not working or am I making this up?